# Twitter API issue (code: 349, message: 'You cannot send messages to this user.') in node.js

Tags: node.js, meteor, twitter

I am sending message by using direct_messages/events/new method in Node.js by using API,

But i am getting the errors like { code: 349, message: 'You cannot send messages to this user.' }

please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the user is not following you or has blocked you, then you will not be able to send messages to the user.

Comment: But I was just able to send one of the users who doesn't follow me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also send messages to a user that is not following you but has DM'd you (e.g. if your id accepts DMs without requiring mutual following). However, if the user is not following you/has blocked you (as mentioned by Andy Piper) or has not DM'd you, you'll receive the "code: 349, message: 'You cannot send messages to this user.'" error. Tested via postman using the direct message api (https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/events/new.json).